# How to stack column values in a single Dataframe cell

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame of one column consisting many values. I want to stack all those values into one cell of same or another dataframe.

```
column_df = 
index    voltage
 0      5.143590
 1      5.175285
 2      5.231214
 3      6.040188
 4      7.776510
 5      9.540277
 6     11.476937
 7     13.277916
 8     15.088566
 9     16.895921
 10    18.701332
```

I want to stack column values into a dataframe cell. Finally I want to achieve something like 
Expected output:

```
cell_df = 
index                    voltage
  0      [ 5.14359 , 5.175285, 5.231214,  6.040188,  7.77651 ,  9.540277,        11.476937, 13.277916, 15.088566, 16.895921, 18.701332]
```

My code is:

```
cell_df = pd.Dataframe()  
cell_df['voltage'][0] = np.array([column_df['voltage']])
```

Present output:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the "voltage" series as a list and use it in your `cell_df` constructor:

```py
cell_df = pd.DataFrame({"voltage": [column_df["voltage"].tolist()]})
```